# Regarding regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

what would be the regex for

> October 12, 2017 10:07 am

I had tried `"^[A-Z][a-z1-10]\s[1-31]\,[2016-2018]\s[0-12]\:[00-60]\sAM|PM]$"`

but this is not working.
Please help

Comment: why would you use regex for this, why not try to parse using simpledateformat?

Comment: well, your regex is wrong. And, like ScaryWombat says, why not try parsing it?

Comment: I think you need to go back and review how to do regex (and why that won't work here).

Comment: A regex matching exactly that string (and nothing else) is `October 12, 2017 10:07 am`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+\s[0-9]{2}\,\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\sam|pm$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant accept any arbitrary characters instead of month name, thus you should go for the following solution:

```
^(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|Novermber|December)\s+([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1]|[1-9]|),\s*[1-2]\d{3}\s+[0-1][0-2]:[0-5][0-9]\s*[ap]m\s*$
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxu2qo/1/)